# How to define grunt task that is based on other task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

For example I define my own task named `jasmine`. It is based on the task `server`.

If I call `grunt server jasmine` - it's ok. But I want to declare that dependency inside my task.

`grunt.task.run` - add task to the queue (after my task).
`grunt.task.requires` - only check dependency, not run it...

Does any way exist to run `server` task before my `jasmine` task?

P.S. I don't want to create `jasmine_orig` task and then `.registerTask('jasmine', 'server jasmine_orig')`. It looks like silly.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think creating another task that executes both tasks look silly. There are many ways to do this, but without knowing what "silliness" you want to avoid, It's hard to know what the best answer is.

Comment: `jasmine` task should depends on `server` task and could not be ran without it. But what if `server` task is already in use (maybe watching of files is active)? I want to check it out and run server task, that is a dependency before my `jasmine` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the server task is currently written, no this isn't possible. However, you may be able to do what you want by using the [grunt-connect plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect), or [rolling your own](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/docs/task_server.md#roll-your-own) `grunt server` task. The source for the built-in one is here:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/tasks/server.js

As you can see, there isn't much to it, other than reading a config, starting a connect server, and possibly logging when `--debug` is passed. You could, in fact, copy all of that code into a helper (woefully underdocumented, I'm afraid), and call it from your jasmine task.

It's probably a good idea to start a separate server for your tests (for test independence), but if you needed to save the resources for some reason, or you find multiple servers distasteful in some other way, you'll have to write some custom task code to check if the server is there, and then start the server if it's not.

Probably the best solution is the following:

1. install the grunt-contrib-connect npm package:

   ```
   npm install grunt-contrib-connect --save-dev
   ```
2. Make configurations for your dev and test environments:

   ```
   connect: {
     dev: {
       base: 'path/to/serve',
       port: 8000
     },
     test: {
       base: 'path/to/serve',
       port: 8001
     }
   }
   ```
3. Register a `test` task that runs `grunt server:test jasmine` for you.

   ```
   grunt.registerTask('test', 'server:test jasmine')
   ```

Comment: Great idea to start few servers via `grunt-contrib-connect`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One partial solution is to define the steps for specific tasks as variables. Then, you can concatenate them like such:

```
var buildSteps = [ ... ];
var distDevSteps = [ ... ];
grunt.registerTask('build', buildSteps);
grunt.registerTask('dist_dev', [].concat(buildSteps, distDevSteps));
```